# Can Vidyo be integrated to Unity?

Tags: vidyo

I would like to make a mobile game with Unity 2D that includes a videocall between two players. Is it possible to make this using vidyo?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration to Unity is not supported at this moment.